# Stacking modal dialogs in SWT

Tags: java, macos, swt

I've a problem stacking dialog windows in pure SWT.
It's a little bit complicated to describe it but I try it: I have a starter class which builds the main application window. From the main window I open a first modal dialog by clicking a button. And from this first dialog I open a second dialog which is a modal window again. This second dialog contains only one label and no other components.
The use case is to have the main GUI and a first dialog in which the user can manage menu shortcuts. For this purpose the window contains for example a dorpdown list with the existing shortcuts and a button to change a selected one. By clicking this button the second window is opened in which the user will prompt for pressing the new keys.

My code looks like this:

```
public class Runner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    MainWindow app = new MainWindow(display);
    app.open();
    display.dispose();
  }
}

public class MainWindow {
  private Display display;
  private Shell shell;

  public MainWindow(Display display) {
    this.display = display;
    createContents();
  }

  public void open() {
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
  }

  private void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        showFirstWindow();
      }
    });
  }

  private void showFirstWindow() {
    FirstWindow firstWindow = new FirstWindow(shell);
    firstWindow.open();
  }
}

public class FirstWindow extends Dialog {
  private Display display;
  private Shell shell;

  public FirstWindow(Shell parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
    display = parent.getDisplay();
    createContents();
  }

  public void open() {
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
  }

  private void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        showSecondWindow();
      }
    });
  }

  private void showSecondWindow() {
    SecondWindow secondWindow = new SecondWindow(shell);
    secondWindow.open();
  }
}

public class SecondWindow extends Dialog {
  private Display display;
  private Shell shell;
  private Label label;

  public SecondWindow(Shell parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
    display = parent.getDisplay();
    createContents();
  }

  public void open() {
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
  }

  private void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());

    label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label.setLocation(10, 10);
    label.setSize(200, 13);
    label.setText("prompt text");
  }
}
```

Under Windows this construct works fine but under Mac OS X the second dialog is invisible. It's interesting that the KeyPressedHandler is triggered but the window and thus the prompt message is not shown.
Is it not possible to overlay a few dialogs in OS X or is it a bug of SWT or is it a problem in my code? I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: Are you running the program in full screen mode? If so this is Eclipse bug [478975](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478975)

Comment: @greg: I don't maximize the application programmatically and the full-screen-button in the titlebar is still clickable so I would say - no the application doesn't run in full screen mode. You think it's a bug of SWT? So have you kindly a proposal for me to reorganize my GUI to work for the described use case?

Comment: There is a known bug when the app runs full screen, I was just checking it was not that. When not full screen this should be possible.

Comment: You might give an answer if you provide the minimal code that can actually be run so people can do some testing.

Comment: What's wrong with my posted code? I mean with the classes you can exactly reproduce the problem and so it should be good for testing.

Comment: It is not complete, it can't just be put in to Eclipse and run. If you want someone to spend time sorting out your code it is up to you to make it as straightforward as possible.

Comment: There were only the click handlers missing but no problem - I completed it. More code is not necessary to reproduce the effect.